# Using Perl's fork() to parallelize processing

Tags: perl, multiprocessing

I use bash scripts to process last names through a Perl program, and I parallelize the execution like this, by name initials:

```
for alpha in a b c d e f g h i j
do
    perl process_names.pl -init $alpha &
done
wait
```

I've determined that ~10 parallel executions is about optimal, to complete the work quickly but also to leave the computer to do other work.

But this is inefficient, because some letters have more records to process than others, so sometimes 8 or 9 have finished and there's a lingering program execution during which I'd like to begin processing another batch of name initials.

---

So I wanted to use Perl's `fork` to keep 10 processes running at a time. Imagine that the following code block is run by a program invocation like this:
`perl process_names.pl -all`
Then the `system()` call would invoke the program as child processes, like this:
`perl process_names.pl -init a`, `b`, `c`, etc., processing 10 at a time until all are finished.

This *seems* to work fine. No zombie processes that I can tell, work gets done, and it's faster. But I've never used the bare `fork` interface like this. Am I doing it correctly? Are there any gotchas that I've overlooked?

```
my $data = {
  'remaining' => ['a' ... 'z'],
  'running'   => [],  # <- currently running list of child pids
  'children'  => [],  # <- all child pids; added to list as spawned, then waited on
  'cur_init'  => ''
};

while (scalar @{$data->{remaining}}) {
    if (scalar @{$data->{running}} < 10) {

        $data->{cur_init} = shift(@{$data->{remaining}});

        my $pid = fork();
        if (!$pid) {
            ## CHILD ##
            system('perl ' . abs_path($0) . ' -init ' . $data->{cur_init});
            exit;
        } else {
            ## PARENT ##
            push(@{$data->{running}}, $pid);
            push(@{$data->{children}}, $pid);
        }
    }

    my @new;
    foreach my $cpid (@{$data->{running}}) {
        my $is_running = kill(0, $cpid);
        if ($is_running) {
           push(@new, $cpid);
        }
    }
    $data->{running} = \@new;
}

foreach my $pid (@{$data->{children}}) {
    waitpid $pid, 0;
}
```

Comment: This is my first contribution to Code Review and it was immediately met with a downvote. I read a bit to make sure that my question accords to the rules, and might be generally helpful to others.

Is there something I should add or annotate?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the downvote is for. I find your question is fine. It's working, it's real code (which I hope), there is a detailed description. A perfect question (or not? any perl experts out there?). I'm giving you a +1.

Comment: `kill(0, $cpid)` should tell you process is still running even if finished (zombie). `use POSIX ":sys_wait_h"; my $is_dead = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) >0;` to check if pid finished, and reap the pid if so.

Comment: You're reinventing [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager)